# plot variable for one country relative to another

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have time series data for several countries and several years, say Italy, Spain, USA. I'd like to plot the data for some countries *relative* to another country: say plot real GDP per capita in Italy and Spain as a percentage of the USA.

This is what the data looks like:

```
head(pwt)
         country isocode       year     rgdpo      pop
ESP-1950   Spain     ESP 1950-01-01  85002.27 27.99278
ESP-1951   Spain     ESP 1951-01-01 100241.94 28.22724
ESP-1952   Spain     ESP 1952-01-01 105170.11 28.47847
ESP-1953   Spain     ESP 1953-01-01 101322.59 28.73209
ESP-1954   Spain     ESP 1954-01-01 114573.78 28.98774
ESP-1955   Spain     ESP 1955-01-01 120839.95 29.24542
```

The variable of interest here, "Real GDP Per Capita", is obtained as `rgdpo/pop`

Sadly I didn't get very far. I know how to select a whole column, e.g. `pwt['rgdpo']` or `pwt$rgdpo`, but then not sure how to restrict this to a particular country without completely dismantling the data frame. (I would know how to create variables for each country by using the subset function and then creating the relative variable by dividing and then recreating a dataframe and then plotting, but I would like to learn the smart way to do things here).

I'd like the solution to be robust to the presence of NAs or to a missing date (missing dates could be replaced by NAs)

I have used ggplot2 in my example, but I'm open minded to a base-R solution too (authors: Hadley Wickham, Winston Chang, http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/).

To obtain a reproducible example, I am getting data from the pwt8 package (author: Achim Zeileis, http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwt8/).

```
# Get data
# install.packages("pwt8")
library("pwt8")
data("pwt8.0")
# names(pwt8.0)

# use -subset- to get specifc countries and variables.
countries <- c("USA", "ESP", "ITA")
variables <- c("country", "isocode", "year", "rgdpo", "pop")
pwt <- subset(pwt8.0, isocode %in% countries, select = variables)

# Plot GDP PER CAPITA with ggplot
library("ggplot2")
pwt$year<-as.Date(paste0(pwt$year,"-01-01"),format="%Y-%m-%d") # year as Date
ggp <- ggplot(pwt,aes(x=year,y=rgdpo/pop,color=as.factor(isocode),group=isocode)) + 
geom_line()  
ggp <- ggp + 
xlab("") +
ylab("") +  
ggtitle("Real GDP Per Capita (international $, 2005 prices, chain)") +
theme(legend.title = element_blank() ) + 
coord_trans(y = "log10")
ggp <- ggp + coord_cartesian(xlim=as.Date(c("2000-01-01","2012-01-01")),ylim=c(22000,45000))
ggp
```

[image]

**Solution: thanks to Hong Ooi!**

```
require("plyr")
pwt <- ddply(pwt, .(country), transform, gdppc.usa=(rgdpo/pop)/within(subset(pwt, isocode=="USA"),gdppc<-rgdpo/pop)$gdppc)
library("ggplot2")
ggp <- ggplot(subset(pwt,isocode==c("ESP","ITA")),aes(x=year,y=gdppc.usa,color=as.factor(isocode),group=isocode)) + 
geom_line()  
ggp <- ggp + 
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +  
  ggtitle("Real GDP Per Capita Relative to USA (international $, 2005 prices, chain)") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank() ) 
ggp
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform your data before plotting it:

```
require(plyr)
usa <- within(subset(pwt8.0, isocode=="USA"), gdppop <- rgdpo/pop)

# send this to ggplot2
dat <- ddply(pwt8.0, .(country), transform, gdppop_usa=(rgdpo/pop)/usa$gdppop)
```

Comment: Thanks Hong Ooi. Unfortunately this doesn't work. I think neither line does what it is intended to do. The first line creates a variable for GDP per capita. The use of subset inside within does not appear to have an effect. The first line gives the same result as _pwt <- within(pwt, gdppc <- rgdpo/pop)_ Any thought why that is? The second line divides Spanish GDP per capita by Spanish GDP per capita, etc., so that the variable gdppop_usa in dat is equal to 1 everywhere...

Comment: Gah, typo. `country="USA"` should be `country=="USA"`.

Comment: I get it! Thanks a lot. Actually, rather than "country", it should be "isocode", `usa <- within(subset(pwt, isocode=="USA"), gdppop <- rgdpo/pop)`